# Remove all Adobe Flash (Object) advertisment

Tags: jquery, object

I'm scraping some websites and I would like to get rid of the Adobe Flash advertisements on the page. I assume they are "objects" so I did:

```
window.setInterval(MyFunction, 900);

function MyFunction() { 

  $('object').remove();

alert('test'); 

}
```

I see the alert, but the "objects" are not removed. How is that possible? What else can I try?

This is how (one of) the advertisements looks:

```
<script src="http://ad.nl.doubleclick.net/adj/P4442.Nu.nl/home;sz=468x60,728x90;dcopt=ist;tile=1;kw=;tt=1000;gr=-5;rg=0;nk=0;u=m6re350ar;;ord=4884951752610505?" type="text/javascript" style="position: relative; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; width: auto; height: auto; border: none; float: left; background-image: none; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;"></script>
```

Comment: Can you add the HTML? Seems to be working fine over [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UPfwA/).

Comment: @MarcoK You mean the entire page? If so; No, The page is to big. It wouldn't matter anyway, its just HTML nothing special about it

Comment: it works, are you sure you didn't forget to include jquery library?

maybe you start it before page is loaded, try this:

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('object').remove();
})

Comment: @vladkras Im doing other Jquery stuff as well, it all works

Comment: I added the code of the advertisements to my question

Comment: @vladkras Unfortunately that also doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your flash ads may be using `<embed>` elements instead of `<object>`. For example, I just tried loading http://www.drudgereport.com/ a few times and found both element types at various times. You can find out which ones are present by logging `$('object').length` and `$('embed').length`. To remove them all you can use:

```
$('embed,object').length
```

So, with some logging code added to your function:

```
function MyFunction() {
    console.log( 'Objects:', $('object').length );
    console.log( 'Embeds:', $('embed').length );
    $('embed,object').remove();
    console.log( 'Objects after:', $('object').length );
    console.log( 'Embeds after:', $('embed').length );
}
```

It's also possible that your 0.9 second timeout isn't enough. After running your code and waiting a bit, you could try those `console.log()` calls again and see what the results are.

Comment: Thank you very much:) Example Console: `Objects: 2
Embeds: 3 
Objects after: 0 
Embeds after: 0` I sometimes however do get some ads in Iframe. I can't get to its content. I assume because of cross-browser restriction. So is removing the iframes my only option?

Comment: I meant to say cross-domain

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like you need to use `$('embed,iframe,object').remove();` in that case. Of course there may be legitimate iframes that you end up removing this way too. You're right that you can't see inside an iframe from another domain, but you can see the iframe's `src` and other attributes, so maybe you could distinguish based on that.

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('object').remove();  
}, 900);
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are having object tag in your html view?

Comment: I added the code of what I see in console to my question `<script src="http://ad.nl.doubleclick.....`

Comment: That `setTimeout()` code is identical to the code in the original question, except that it doesn't have the `alert()`. Using a named function vs. a function expression doesn't affect what the code does.

Comment: you can use $('script')..remove(":contains('the text you can find in ad script')"), make sure you are using correct text

Comment: @Prateek Shukla Thanks but the problem with that is that the ads are always changing (almost on every refresh)